# Exporting blank values into a .txt file - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to export multiple matrices of unequal lengths into a delimited .txt file thus I have been padding the shorter matrices with 0's such that `dlmwrite` can use `horzcat` without error:

```
dlmwrite(filename{1},[a,b],'delimiter','\t')
```

However ideally I do not want the zeroes to appear in the .txt file itself - but rather the entries are left blank.

Currently the .txt file looks like this:

```
55875   3.1043e+05
56807   3.3361e+05
57760   3.8235e+05
58823   4.2869e+05
59913   4.3349e+05
60887   0
61825   0
62785   0
63942   0
65159   0
66304   0
67509   0
68683   0
69736   0
70782   0
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
55875   3.1043e+05
56807   3.3361e+05
57760   3.8235e+05
58823   4.2869e+05
59913   4.3349e+05
60887   
61825   
62785   
63942   
65159   
66304   
67509   
68683   
69736   
70782
```

Is there anyway I can do this? Is there an alternative to `dlmwrite` which will mean I do not need to have matrices of equal lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in the numeric data and convert to string and then add proper whitespaces to have the final output as string based cell array, which you can easily write into the output text file.

**Stage 1:** Get the cell of strings corresponding to the numeric data from column vector inputs `a`, `b`, `c` and so on -

```
%// Concatenate all arrays into a cell array with numeric data
A = [{a} {b} {c}] %// Edit this to add more columns

%// Create a "regular" 2D shaped cell array to store the cells from A
lens = cellfun('length',A)
max_lens = max(lens)

A_reg = cell(max_lens,numel(lens))
A_reg(:) = {''}
A_reg(bsxfun(@le,[1:max_lens]',lens)) = cellstr(num2str(vertcat(A{:}))) %//'

%// Create a char array that has string data from input arrays as strings
wsp = repmat({'   '},max_lens,1) %// Create whitespace cell array
out_char = [];
for iter = 1:numel(A)
    out_char = [out_char char(A_reg(:,iter)) char(wsp)]
end
out_cell = cellstr(out_char)
```

**Stage 2:** Now, that you have `out_cell` as the cell array that has the strings to be written to the text file, you have two options next for the writing operation itself.

Option 1 -

```
dlmwrite('results.txt',out_cell(:),'delimiter','')
```

Option 2 -

```
outfile = 'results.txt';
fid = fopen(outfile,'w');
for row = 1:numel(out_cell)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',out_cell{row});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this step by step to understand it. After executing p1 and the first dlmwrite, it returns the error: Error using dlmwrite (line 112)
The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix.

Comment: (when using my own input data).

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Check out the other approach added at the end, if that works?

Comment: That seems to work perfectly. Quite a lot to understand here! How would you expand this to, for example, deal with 3 input matrices rather than 2?

Comment: Also would this method work with 3 matrices of unequal length and where one is not always larger than the other?

Comment: That works perfectly. Bsxfun is so useful! Why does out_cell only contain a single column?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Yeah that's what `bsxfun` is! About `out_cell` being one column, that's how one can concatenate all input vector elements into a "single stream" of strings which is helpful because of the size differences between input vectors. And then it becomes easier to write back that "stream" into a text file! Hope that makes at least some sense!

Comment: Ahh, I understand! I can't seem to get fprintf to tab-delimit the columns with \t. What is the best way to do this? I thought it would be simple as %s\t\n.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann You can use the ASCII value of TAB, which is 9 there in wsp - wsp = repmat({char(9)},max_lens,1)

Answer (score 3):

If a is always longer than b you could split vector a into two vectors of same length as vector b and the rest:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]';
b = [9 8 7 ]';

len = numel(b);
dlmwrite( 'foobar.txt', [a(1:len), b ], 'delimiter', '\t' );
dlmwrite( 'foobar.txt', a(len+1:end), 'delimiter', '\t', '-append');
```

Comment: Really nice and simple method. Unfortunately one is not always larger than the other and I may also have more than 2 matrices to handle in future. Perhaps I can adapt this approach...